# Is there a way to monitor push certificate validity & expiration in Azure Notification Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I want to monitor the validity of my APNS certificate (`.p12` file) I've uploaded to Azure Notification Hub, but I could not find a way to monitor this with Azure's tooling.

A possible solution for me would be to create a cronjob that regularly downloads the push certificate via [the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/read-notification-hub), and checks the validity from the certificate embedded in [the response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/create-notification-hub#request-body).

However, I would like a solution that doesn't involve me downloading the stored certificate and manually checking whether the expiration date has passed. It would also be great if I could get an alert about the expiration date coming up (eg. a week in advance) so I have some time to prepare a new push certificate.

Can this be done from the Azure Portal, and if yes, where can I find the configuration option(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this feature does not exist at the moment, azure cannot determine in advanced whether the APNS certificate is about to expire or not, however, there is a notification being sent from Apple to apple id email address prior to certificate expiry as kind of a heads-up.
On Azure there is Alert feature under Monitor that notifies customer when there is APNS expired channel error, not sure if you are interested in that.